# Kafka producer skipping messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to write data from a file to a kafka topic. My code looks like this:

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", <bootstrapServers>);
    properties.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
    properties.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
    properties.put("retries",100);
    properties.put("linger.ms",5);
    properties.put("acks", "all");

    KafkaProducer<Object, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

    try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"))) {
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, line));
        }
  producer.flush();
        Logger.log("Done producing data messages. Total no of records produced:" + count);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException e) {
        Throwables.propagate(e);
    } finally {
        producer.close();
    }
```

The size of the data is above 1 million records.

When I check the offset of data on brokers using following command, there are only half of the messages (around 5,00,000) are written on the topic:

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <broker_list> --time -1 --topic <topic_name>
```

Output of the above command:

```
topic_name:1:292954
topic_name:0:296787
```

What changes should I do in approach to make sure that all the  are written on the topic.

Comment: Can you show the actual output of the GetOffsetShell command ?

Comment: Added the output in the question.

Comment: What is the value of count in application log file? Does it show 1m ?

Comment: Yes the count in application log is 1008179 which matches the no of records on file.

Comment: Try adding a callback arg to your send method to see if the messages are actually being ack'd and committed

Answer (score 0):

The send message is asynchronous. You may be checking the offsets before all the messages are processed.

Comment: Log retention is 24 hrs. And I am checking messages right after producing message which takes hardly 4-5 minutes.

Comment: you completely changed answer.

Comment: Yeah my bad I thought about it and realized retention wouldn't be an issue, I forgot to refresh before changing

Comment: But yeah you should check the broker logs and see if they are still processing the messages even after you see the done producing log message.

Comment: I checked offsets again after several hours. Still the offset value is same. Means no new records are written.